# Iframe using extjs

Tags: iframe, extjs, window

I am trying to use extjs to display an iframe. It works but i'm having trouble editing some of the styles. 
For example, i don't want the border of the window and iframe to show. I tried border: false, and frame: false but they don't seem to do the job

```
function buildIframe(wgt_placeholder_id){
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        width : 1100,
        height: 700,
        layout : 'fit',
        bodyStyle: {
            top: '25px',
            left: '80px',
            z-index: '1'
        },
        frame: false,
        border: false,
        closable: false,
        renderTo: wgt_placeholder_id, 
        items : [{
            frame: false,
            border: false,
            xtype : "component",
            autoEl : {
                tag : "iframe",
                src: "http://google.com"
            }
        }]
    }).show();
```

also bodyStyle: {} does not apply the styles

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `border:0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `frameborder` attribute:

```
autoEl: {
    ...
    frameborder: 0
}
```